# Creating a question-answer chatbot

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language

I was thinking of creating a chatbot for providing info about my college as a side-project, which aims to answer questions like "How many swimming pools are there?" to "How many lecture halls are there in Building X?". Upon discussion with seniors, they advised me to create graphs and then use something called NER to traverse it. This my first entry into the domain of NLP, ML, Neural Networks, etc. Can someone advise me if this is achievable, and if yes, what technologies should I study to achieve this?

Comment: This does not sound like a good first NLP project. Start with something simpler, like a classification task.

Answer (score 1):

Tim is right. You are diving into different domains here. I would start first at understanding, how speech is processed/handled in our favorite DS languages (`Python/R` idk if its possible in `Julia`). That means you have to know how Python or R deals with

```
- Part-of-Speech Tagging, 
- Stemming, 
- Lemmatizer, 
- Tokenizer
- etc..
```

At first you have to "mine text" and read it correctly into your code before analysing anything with NLP.

What if one of the questions for the college was "Is the cafeteria any good?
Then you should also deep dive into `sentiment analysis`.

We do not know enough about your project. The thing is, do you only accept "how" answers? If your chatbot only accepts: "How"  .... "[specific location]" ["object"] "[amount of object]", then you wont probably need so much NLP. But if you want to do a flexible chatbot that reacts to different questions. Stick to proceed language first.

In Python we use NLTK package for example to do mostly all of it, https://www.guru99.com/nltk-tutorial.html

in R we need different libraries and there exists a lot more libraries:

NLP (for text mining and doing a little bit analysis) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NLP/NLP.pdf,
corpus (not the function corpus here) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corpus/corpus.pdf,
rJava (is needed for other NLP libraries, that they work) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/rJava.pdf
RDRPOSTagger (install over github) https://github.com/ck37/RDRPOSTagger
tm https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf

I hope you will get on with your project.

---UPDATE--
as the OP asked about graph structures I added this opinion:

It depends on the task you try to accomplish, e.g. if you want to store data that heavily relies on associtaions like in an association network, e.g. 'tell me what you think of this brand' than there is some sort central node who can grow in several directions, depths and with weights, but the edges in this case contain weight to represents connotations and may be strengths of the association, you dont have. You just want to find an answer to a question, where the answer is always, well a number as it seems.

You even neet no optimization graph, you have not such complex questions, where is speed is needed so that the chatbot still fands a quick answer while understanding a 'wide-opened' formulated question.

A directed graph with adjacency matrix may be a solution: https://www.upgrad.com/blog/graphs-in-data-structure/

Starting with the "question" word, in the root, and then looking for the next "object".... until you hit the final node/edge that leads to the answer, the number, e.g. 5 feet of depth of the pool. >ou have several edges going from the intitial How/What, depending on the objects that are available to ask, there may be an 'adjacented'edge that shows, if there is an answer to the original question. Thus the directed graph looks a little bit like a tree in the end.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/all-you-need-to-know-about-tree-data-structures-bceacb85490c/

All the best,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I aim to answer only fact based questions initially, hence "Is the cafeteria any good?" is not expected.

Comment: But it might not be a "how" only as "what is the depth of the swimming pool?" is also valid

Comment: Ok if sentiment is out of the way you still have to deal with the other topics. There you will get the needed technologies to, e.g. look at that link, this describes a simple chatbot in python, and the keywords nltk and corpus for example are also highlighted: https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-creating-a-rule-based-chatbot/

Comment: Is a graph a good medium of storing data?

Comment: I updated my original post to give you an answer on this topic

Comment: Thanks. Also is there any technique/algorithm that can point "What is the number of pools?" and "How many pools are there?" to the same location without me having to hardcode it? Googling it a bit seems to return on the lines of sentiment analysis

Comment: I dont know of a specific alg. of this, but maybe a naives or multinomial bayes, would help in classyfying the  what and how into question words first, which you could then use to build up your further application. Thus, you train your algorithm on your specific words, e.g. is the first word interrogative, e.g. "How" you predict your question nodes, and after a question was entered your aklgorithm predicts the class and then the tree where he has to look at. It is then possible tha your alg. has not to divide between how and what, as it belongs to the same predicted class of node